# Why is the particle に used between カツ and たべられない and what does 入った可能性 mean?

Tags: meaning, particle-に

I know that **食べられない** can be a passive or a potential verb, but in this case I think it is used like a potential verb, so I don't know why that **に** is there.

About **入った可能性**, I think it is a *relative clause* so **入った{はいった}** is modifying **可能性{かのうせい}** but, I don't get what it means.

> ～は冷凍のカツ**に**食べられない物が**入った可能性**があるため、捨てることにしました。

I saw this [here](http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10010376841000/k10010376841000.html).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think the verb to do with に is 入る, not 食べられる.

Comment: Agreed. It makes things flow a lot better when you put it like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got the wrong idea about what modifies what :)

Look at this part closely:

> 食べられない物が入った可能性がある

If you isolate this part, it becomes clear that it means "inedible things that may have gotten in"(or lit. "a possibility that inedible things got in").　可能性がある means 可能性(possibility）＋がある(exists), so it literally means "a possibility exists".
Now let's add some more to this sentence:

> 食べられない物が入った可能性があるため、捨てることにしました.

It is a lot more clear now that this means "due to the possibility of inedible things that got in, I decided to throw away".

Now that we got that section clear, we're only left with the first part of the sentence. When we add it we can see the appropriate context and how everything is modified:

> **冷凍のカツに**｜*食べられない物が入った可能性があるため*｜、捨てることにしました

Comment: I read that phrase many times and I didn't see it in that way XD. Thanks you all for helping me.